# Exception: Invalid argument: label

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I am new to google scripting. My script goes through desired gmail label parses all emails in all threads. This part works nicely. Now I wanted to add new label to the thread that was just processed. It did not work for me. I found this SO question ["Invalid Argument" error with addLabel(label) method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57404568/invalid-argument-error-with-addlabellabel-method) but it did not answer the issue.

So I tested it even more and found out that even this code

```
// Add label MyLabel to the first thread in the inbox
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("MyLabel");
var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
firstThread.addLabel(label);
```

from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#addlabellabel

is throwing the same error `Exception: Invalid argument: label`

Any idea how to add a label to a thread?

**UPDATE** the label `MyLabel` does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, the existing label name is used. So when new label name, which is not existing, is used, such error occurs. In order to use the new label name, it is required to create new label. So when your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var newLabelName = "sample1";  // Please set the new label name.
var newLabel = GmailApp.createLabel(newLabelName);
var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
firstThread.addLabel(newLabel);
```

#### Reference:

- [createLabel(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#createlabelname)

### Added:

About your additional question of `how can I check if a label already exists?`, I would like to answer. In this case, you can check it using `getUserLabelByName`. When `name` of `GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(name)` is existing, `GmailLabel` object is returned. When `name` of `GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(name)` is NOT existing, `null` is returned. This can be used. When above script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var newLabelName = "sample1";
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(newLabelName);
if (!label) {
  label = GmailApp.createLabel(newLabelName);
}
var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
firstThread.addLabel(label);
```

Or, as the simple script, you can also use the following script.

```
var newLabelName = "sample";
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(newLabelName) || GmailApp.createLabel(newLabelName);
var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
firstThread.addLabel(label);
```

- In this modified script, when `newLabelName` is not existing, the label is created as new label. When `newLabelName` is existing, the existing label is used.

Comment: @Radek Thank you for replying. About your additional question, I added it in my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: I'm running a similar script, but in my case I'm getting the error `Exception: Invalid argument: name` when I'm using `GmailApp.getUserLabelByName` The name I'm using begins with an "@" sign in this case - I don't know if that has to do with it, but that is in the name of my label. It is a commonly used "trick" to get the label to go to the top of the list.